# How do I transfer small files quickly over the network with zstd?

Tags: ssh, tar, rsync, file-transfer, zstd

As the question states, I want to backup many small files and send them via ssh to a destination. Does rsync speed things up significantly vs tar?

Answer (score 2):

This works quite well, significantly faster than gzip.

### Push (Upload)

```
tar -c --zstd src_dir | ssh user@dest_addr "cd dest_dir && tar -x --zstd"
```

This does the following

1. Creates a tar file using Zstd and outputs it via STDOUT
2. Connects via ssh, piping STDOUT over the network
3. Reads data from STDIN, and extracts it

##### Custom zstd flags

This uses maximum compression (default level is 3) and multithreading.

```
tar -c -I "zstd -19 -T0" src_dir | ssh user@dest_addr "cd dest_dir && tar -x --zstd"
```

##### With progress

```
tar -c --zstd src_dir | pv --timer --rate | ssh user@dst_addr "cd dest_dir && tar -x --zstd"
```

### Pull (Download)

```
ssh user@dest_addr "tar --zstd -cf - src_dir" | tar -x --zstd --directory dest_dir
```